# How do I set the layout of an HTML table so that it doesn't change when values are entered in the <td> via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please excuse me if I made any mistakes, it's my first post on stack overflow! I'm currently working on a project which is coding a 2048 game from scratch. For that purpose, I have created a table in HTML but when I inject values in that table via JS it changes the size of the row and column [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwgkt.png) when a value is inserted into a children cell and I would like the table layout to be fixed whether the cells are empty or not. I'm guessing there's something wrong in my CSS file but for the life of me I can't find what it is, also I suck at CSS. I tried looking for answers on here like setting the table-layout to fixed but that did not work. Here is what I have in HTML -

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        TableInit();
    });
    
    function TableInit() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $("td").empty().removeClass(); // reset table
            var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) //first random cell
            $("table").find("td").eq(rand1).text(2).addClass("twos"); // setting value and class "2" to first random cell
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); // random for displaying "4" 10% of the time
            if (i == 0)
                val = 4;
            else
                val = 2;
            var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
            while (rand1 == rand2) // to avoid rand1 and rand2 going to the same cell
                rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
            if (val == 2)
                $("table").find("td").eq(rand2).text(val).addClass("twos"); //setting value and class "2" to 2nd random cell
            else
                $("table").find("td").eq(rand2).text(val).addClass("fours"); //setting value and class "4" to 2nd random cell
    
        });
    }
```

```css
    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    table {
        font-size: 40px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    td {
        border: 15px solid rgb(161, 110, 110);
        background-color: LemonChiffon;
        padding: 60px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .twos {
        background-color: rgb(235, 185, 61);
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .fours {
        background-color: rgb(136, 25, 25);
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: rgb(231, 101, 14);
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
    <h1>2048</h1>
    <input type="button" value="New game" id="btn" align="center" class="button" /><br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Has anybody got any idea how to fix my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Try giving your td's a min-width and min-height

Comment: Thank you @Taplar but that did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` and `max-height` properties to be equal and set the `width` and `max-width` properties to be equal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        TableInit();
    });
    
    function TableInit() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $("td").empty().removeClass(); // reset table
            var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16) //first random cell
            $("table").find("td").eq(rand1).text(2).addClass("twos"); // setting value and class "2" to first random cell
            var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9); // random for displaying "4" 10% of the time
            if (i == 0)
                val = 4;
            else
                val = 2;
            var rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
            while (rand1 == rand2) // to avoid rand1 and rand2 going to the same cell
                rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16);
            if (val == 2)
                $("table").find("td").eq(rand2).text(val).addClass("twos"); //setting value and class "2" to 2nd random cell
            else
                $("table").find("td").eq(rand2).text(val).addClass("fours"); //setting value and class "4" to 2nd random cell
    
        });
    }
```

```css
 body {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
        background-color: antiquewhite;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    table {
        font-size: 40px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    td {
        border: 15px solid rgb(161, 110, 110);
        background-color: LemonChiffon;
        padding: 60px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 40px;
        height: 60px;
        max-height: 60px;
        width: 80px;
        max-width: 80px;
    }
    
    .twos {
        background-color: rgb(235, 185, 61);
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .fours {
        background-color: rgb(136, 25, 25);
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    .button {
        background-color: rgb(231, 101, 14);
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center>
    <h1>2048</h1>
    <input type="button" value="New game" id="btn" align="center" class="button" /><br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</center>
```

Comment: Thanks @hev1 - I tried doing what you suggested and also added the min/max-width/height to my "twos" and "fours" classes but the problem remains unfortunately. :(

Comment: @Glyph Did you add `max-height` and `max-width`?

Comment: yep sorry forgot to mention the max ones in my last comment but I did, yes.

Comment: @Glyph And the code you posted was your entire code?

Comment: @Glyph That's strange. Try copying exactly the code I posted.

Comment: Ok, just did that (and re-added the link to the css and JS files which were missing in the HTML code you posted) but no change.

Comment: I can't tell because your code snippet doesn't insert a value in the table cells which is what causes the table line/column to change size

Comment: @Glyph Aren't values inserted when New Game is pressed?

Comment: ah sorry, I'm new on stack overflow and didn't realise the button could be clicked in the code snippet. So... I clicked it and yeah when a value is inserted in a cell it still changes the row and column size of that cell which is what I'm trying to avoid. So to answer your previous question, no your code snippet doesn't reflect what I want.

Comment: @Glyph Replace the `min-width` and `min-height` properties with `width` and `height`.

Comment: @Glyph No problem.